# Java number table weird error

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, math

For school we have to make a number table that lists

- a series of int from 1 to 20
- those same numbers squared and cubed
- the square and cube roots of those numbers.

The first time I made the table the numbers were fine but it wouldn't make organized columns, but when I messed with it a little now it's making columns but the loops are all wrong. Does anyone know what might have happened or how I could fix it?

```
System.out.print ("Enter an integer between 1 and 20.");
    int n= scan.nextInt();
        for (n=1; n<20; n++)
        {   
                System.out.print (n++);
                System.out.print (n*n + "\t" + " "); 
                System.out.print(n*n*n + "\t" + " ");
                System.out.print (dec.format (Math.sqrt(n))+ "\t" + " ");
                System.out.print (dec.format (Math.cbrt(n)) + "\t" + " ");
                System.out.println ();

                }
              }
//these are the original way I did the loops; just a different for-loop for each one right on top of one another.
        //(n=1; n<=20; n++) 
        // (n=1; n<20; n++) 
        // (n=1; n<20; n++) 
        // (n=1; n<20; n++)
```

Comment: if you want it from 1 to 20 change the for loop condition to  for (n=1; n<=20; n++), current will only give till number 19. can your share the screen of the output you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Your first `print` statement is:

```
System.out.print(n++);
```

This contains `n++` which will alter your loop variable. This would muck up your output. Change this to:

```
System.out.print(n);
```

Or better:

```
System.out.print (n + "\t" + " ");
```

Does that fix your issue?

And, as Iqbal noted in a comment, your `for` loop should *include* 20:

```
for (n = 1; n <= 20; n++)
```

Also, what's the point of this code?

```
System.out.print ("Enter an integer between 1 and 20.");
int n= scan.nextInt();
```

This value for `n` is never used.

Comment: Probably wanted some TAB char after the first `print` too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your exact output format desired; but I can see a problem right away with the manner in which the variable n is incremented. You are double incrementing the the variable `n` as shown below

```
//the for loop should be as below.
for (n=1; n<=20; n++)
        {   
                System.out.print (n++); //this line increments n again.Instead of this do System.out.print(n+1);
                System.out.print (n*n + "\t" + " "); 
                System.out.print(n*n*n + "\t" + " ");
```

If you follow the comment  then your program should work as expected. If you are new to Java or programming you would want to really red up on the various operators and the effects they have on the variables they operate upon. For example the unary increment operator `++` used in this program increments the value of the variable and stores it back in the variable itself.

Hope this helps.